# user xxxx not authorized to view the data (state=,code=0) in spark-sql & hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, beeline

I am able to create table in spark-sql using beeline,but when i am trying to run query on created table I am getting error 
"user not authorized to view the data". 
below are the steps which i have perform

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/beeline
!connect jdbc:hive2://server:10000 username password
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename(Name STRING,count INT)  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  STORED AS TEXTFILE  location '/user/xxxx/'
```

when i do show tables i can see table has been created ,but while querying on tables i am getting error.

please help

Comment: Check HiveServer2 logs for more detailed exception. I feel user doesn't have privileges to folder hdfs://user/xxxx

Comment: Check user permissions on the table